# my homepage is completely deindexed by google

Tags: seo, homepage

homepage of my site is completely de indexed by google.when we search cache of our site,it shows 404 error.Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make sure that your home page is not indexed, you should use the site operator `site:example.com`. If it appears on the result list, it's indexed.

The cache `cache:example.com` only proves that there is no cache of your homepage yet. You need to be patient and let the searchers do their job.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually my site homepage is indexed well.But for the last two months only homepage is getting de indexed by google.